# Use Virtual Private Cloud in Blueprint of Apache Brooklyn

Tags: amazon-web-services, jclouds, brooklyn

If a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) is created in Amazon Web Services (AWS) or wherever. Is there any chance to use it (and configure it) in our blueprint to deploy it later via Apache Brooklyn? Has Apache Brooklyn VPC support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a VPC to deploy applications is not possible.

At this moment is missing the full support for VPC (and create/edit/delete for Subnets)

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-796
- https://github.com/jclouds/legacy-jclouds/issues/1393

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot specify a VPC. You can however instruct Brooklyn to use a specific subnet (tied to a VPC) through the `templateOptions` like so:

Within your `brooklyn.properties`:

```
brooklyn.location.named.MY-LOCATION.templateOptions={subnetId: subnet-aa461fec}
```

As a provisioning property within your YAML blueprint:

```
...
provisioning.properties:
  templateOptions: {subnetId: subnet-aa461fec}
...
```